# Match string that contains punctuations, emojis, special characters, some Chinese characters and alpha numeric

Tags: regex

I have a string which has the following format:

```
Foo/FooVersion some info
```

Foo can contain:

1. punctuations
2. special characters
3. emojis
4. alpha numeric
5. Chinese characters

I have this regex to capture the following pattern:

```
^[\+$-¨™®é!?_ó–:—兼职,.&\w\s]+\/\d+[\+\w.-]*
```

It seems quite exhaustive list of character set and I am not sure if it does cover all the characters. What I am looking for is a simplified regex that takes these characters into account and returns true if there is a match. I am using sql.

FooVersion can consists of:

```
start with digit followed by word including dot or hyphen
```

Comment: What's your database? Are you running regex inside of your DB or using a programming language.

Comment: I am running it in AWS Athena (presto db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use such pattern `([^\/]+)\/\1Version.+`

Pattern explanation:

`([^\/]+)` - `[^\/]+` matches on or more characters other than `/` (this is negated character class), `()` means capturing group, so matched text is put into first capturing group

`\/` - match `/` literally

`\1` - back reference to match the same text as was matched by first capturing group

`Version` - match `Version` literally

`.+` - match one or more of any characters (to match rest of a string - this is optional and can be removed)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iveszY/1)

#### Update

To match updated requirements, you should use `([^\/]+)\/\d[a-zA-Z\d.-]+`

What's new is:

`[a-zA-Z\d.-]+` - match on or more characters from set `a-z` (lowercase letters), `A-Z` (uppercase letters), `\d` (digits), `.-` - hyphen or dot

[Updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/WxMM7p/1)

Comment: <> was actually a placeholder and not a pattern. I have edited my question.

Comment: There is no ```Version``` string literally in the pattern.